# Чем проанализировать загрузку диска за определенный период?

Tags: windows-server, поиск-программ

На сервере в определенное время ночью, в случайный день возникает высокая пиковая активность на жесткий диск, которая длится 2 часа. 
Все расписания проверил - нет запланированных задач на это время. Для системы такое поведение тоже странно.
Посоветуйте тул, который можно запустить и потом через неделю посмотреть, кто же использовал дисковое время IOPS